# Can't find an element in a dropdown list - Selenium

Tags: html, xpath, selenium, firebug

I want to find an element in a dropdown list in my Selenium test. I use firebug to find the xpath, but my Selenium code can not find the xpath. I am looking for option value number 2 in the html code below:

```
<div id="accountList_gbselect" class="gb-select text-luc3" style=""> 
    <a class="text-luc3" href="#">Konto: xxxxxx    0 kr</a>
    <select id="accountList" style="width: 300px; display: none;" onchange="submit();" size="1" name="accountList">
        <option value="1xxxxx" selected="selected">Konto: 1xxxxxx    0 kr</option>
        <option value="1xxxxx">Testname: 1xxxxx    6 771 kr</option>
        <option value="5xxxxx">Konto: 5xxxxx    500 kr</option>
    <div class="list">
</div>
```

In my Selenium code I use findElement and I have tried xpath and cssSelector. But can not get it to work. This is how I thought I should write to find the element in the dropdown list:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='accountList']/option[2]")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Select` class.

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("accountList"));
select.selectByVisibleText("text-goes-here");
//or
select.selectByIndex(number);
//or
select.selectByValue("value");
```

Comment: I tried to use the select class but it does not work in this case. I tried with both value and index without any luck...

Comment: How does it not work? What error and/or exception are you seeing?

Comment: The error I got is source not found.. I have the same type of list on other places on the website and they could not either be found.

Comment: Are you sure that the Select class has been correctly imported? You should have `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select` for `Java` or similar for another language showing in your imports.

Answer (score 1):

try to click the `select` or the `button` tag first

and then you can find the element